# Получить unix метку нового дня

Tags: php, функции, unix

к примеру:

сегодня 26.06.2018 в 00:00:00 unix число было таким 1529971200

Вопрос:

есть ли стандартная функция которая показывала бы unix метку нового дня?
если нет, может у кого то есть готовое решение? прошу поделиться!

Мне данная задача нужна для введения статистики уникальных посещений. ip + дата

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как-то так видимо?

```
$ts = (new DateTime())->setTime(0,0)->getTimestamp()
```

или

```
$ts = mktime(0,0,0);
```

Comment: практически, вот только ваше решение показывает unix метку -3 GMT

Comment: мое решение показываает метку с учетом часового пояса в настройках php

Comment: на сколько я знаю unix по умолчанию показывает 0 GMT вне зависимости от настроек сервера. разве не так?

Comment: дак вы описание [`mktime`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mktime.php)-то почитайте?

Comment: значение timestamp в вопросе говорит, что автора интересует когда полночь в UTC¶ mktime() принимает местное время, которое может отличаться от UTC (любая часовая зона с ненулевым UTC сдвигом). Можно поискать аналог timegm функции (обратная к gmtime()).  В питоне решение выглядит как: `DT.datetime(2018,6,26, tzinfo=DT.timezone.utc).timestamp()` — можно аналог в php поискать.

Comment: @jfs `DateTime::setTimezone()`, либо выставлять TZ перед вызовом `mktime` и восстаналивать. Либо как в соседнем ответе `strtotime` указывать с зоной.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде так `strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))`

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить Unix время соответствующее полночи в UTC для указанной даты, [можно gmmktime() функцию использовать](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmmktime.php):

```
echo gmmktime(0,0,0,6,26,2018);
```

[Результат](https://ideone.com/N06JKS):

```
1529971200
```